# Finding The idle Time for a system

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

We have 2 arrays of start times and end times of jobs. Jobs can overlap as in the following two example arrays.

```
startTime = [2.1, 5.0, 8.3, 14.1 ,16.5, 24.2 ,28.1, 40.6 ,42.3 , 45.4 ]
endTime =  [4.0 ,10.0 ,9.3 ,18.1 ,26.5 ,25.3, 36.6 ,60.6, 44.3 ,55.4]
```

We have to calculate the idle time of the system. In this case the calculation is:
`Total idle time = 2.1 + (5.0-4.0) + (14.1-10.0) + (28.1-26.5) + (40.6-36.6) = 12.8 units`

But I am unable to find generic logic. The algorithm must not have complexity greater than O(n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This smells like either a H/W or code challenge...  Here is a general pattern that should work...

The complication in this problem is that jobs can overlap.  So you will need to keep track of how many jobs are “in work”, and accumulate time when 0 jobs are in work.

You want (and can achieve) O(n) efficiency by only traversing each list once, but you *can* traverse them at the same time.  So:

1. Make a variable to keep track of how many jobs are in process.
2. Set up a while loop to loop as long as there are elements in either of the 2 arrays.  Keep track of the index position in both arrays.
3. Compare the lead element in both arrays to find the lesser (earlier).
4. If the earlier is a “start” increase your jobs variable, and vice-versa.
5. If the jobs variable ever is zero, track the start-finish times and keep an accumulation of that too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this could be improved upon but here is a solution:

```
import math
from numpy import arange

def points_in_interval(start, end, step, round_to):
    return [round(point, round_to) for point in arange(start, end, step)]

def decimal_places(step):
    if step > 1:
        round_to = 0
    else:
        round_to = int(round(-math.log(step, 10), 1))
    return round_to

def find_idle_time(start_times, end_times, step=.1):
    max_time = 0
    round_to = decimal_places(step)
    time_points = {'init'}
    for start, end in zip(start_times, end_times):
        if end > max_time:
            max_time = end
        time_points.update(points_in_interval(start, end, step, round_to))
    return round(max_time - (len(time_points) - 1) * step, round_to)
```

I think it's technically O(m, n) where m is the number of intervals and n is 1/`step`. But it is linear in number of intervals, and n isn't going to be increasing arbitrarily; it's limited by the precision with which Python can represent numbers.  Anyway, the use of a set is the key to dealing with the fact that the intervals are overlapping, since any value can only be added to a set once, and data structures that use hashes don't have to loop to check for uniqueness. Keeping track of `max_time` means you don't have to spend time complexity sorting.

Comment: You shouldn’t need to implement time stepping when you are given discrete times.